# Using hana filter on tuple of types: "use of boost::hana::not_equal_t before deduction of auto"

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, auto, boost-hana

I'm trying to filter a `hana::tuple_t`, which from my understanding is just a `hana::tuple` of `hana::type` objects.

I looked at some code from [the example in the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html#tutorial-quickstart-any), which is:

```cpp
template <typename Any>
auto switch_(Any& a) {
  return [&a](auto ...cases_) {
    auto cases = hana::make_tuple(cases_...);
    auto default_ = hana::find_if(cases, [](auto const& c) {
      return hana::first(c) == hana::type_c<default_t>;
    });
    static_assert(default_ != hana::nothing,
      "switch is missing a default_ case");
    auto rest = hana::filter(cases, [](auto const& c) {
      return hana::first(c) != hana::type_c<default_t>;
    });
    // ...
  };
}
```

In this case (again, if my understanding is correct), `cases` is a `hana::tuple` of `hana::pair` objects, where the `first` element in the pair is a `hana::type` object.

So here is my code, which should work the same way:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/filter.hpp>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

int main() {
    auto types_tuple = hana::tuple_t<int, float, char>;
    auto filtered_tuple = hana::filter(types_tuple, [](auto const & type) {
        return type != hana::type_c<float>;
    });
}
```

The goal here being for `filtered_tuple` to end up being the same as `hana::tuple_t<int, char>`.

This does not compile. I get a long compiler output, but the relevant part (I think) is:

```
/usr/include/boost/hana/detail/operators/comparable.hpp: In instantiation of ‘constexpr auto boost::hana::detail::operators::operator!=(X&&, Y&&) [with X = boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_&; Y = const boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_&; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]’:
/path/to/test.cpp:9:21:   required from ‘main()::<lambda(auto:1)> [with auto:1 = boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/filter.hpp:105:34:   required by substitution of ‘template<class ... X> boost::hana::detail::filter_indices<static_cast<bool>(boost::hana::detail::decay<decltype((((const boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main::__lambda0>*)this)->boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main::__lambda0>::pred)(static_cast<X&>(boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices::operator()::x))), typename std::remove_reference<decltype((((const boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main::__lambda0>*)this)->boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main::__lambda0>::pred)(static_cast<X&>(boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices::operator()::x)))>::type>::type::value) ...> boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >::operator()<X ...>(X&& ...) const [with X = {boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_&, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_&, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_&}]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/basic_tuple.hpp:117:39:   required from ‘static constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::unpack_impl<boost::hana::basic_tuple_tag>::apply(boost::hana::detail::basic_tuple_impl<std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, _Idx ...>, Xn ...>&, F&&) [with long unsigned int ...i = {0, 1, 2}; Xn = {boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_}; F = boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/unpack.hpp:47:29:   required from ‘constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::unpack_t::operator()(Xs&&, F&&) const [with Xs = boost::hana::basic_tuple<boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_>&; F = boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/tuple.hpp:225:32:   required from ‘static constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::unpack_impl<boost::hana::tuple_tag>::apply(Xs&&, F&&) [with Xs = boost::hana::tuple<boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_>&; F = boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/unpack.hpp:47:29:   required from ‘constexpr decltype(auto) boost::hana::unpack_t::operator()(Xs&&, F&&) const [with Xs = boost::hana::tuple<boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_>&; F = boost::hana::detail::make_filter_indices<main()::<lambda(auto:1)> >]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/filter.hpp:123:29:   required from ‘static constexpr auto boost::hana::filter_impl<S, boost::hana::when<boost::hana::Sequence<S>::value> >::apply(Xs&&, const Pred&) [with Xs = boost::hana::tuple<boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_>&; Pred = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>; S = boost::hana::tuple_tag]’
/usr/include/boost/hana/filter.hpp:48:29:   required from ‘constexpr auto boost::hana::filter_t::operator()(Xs&&, Pred&&) const [with Xs = boost::hana::tuple<boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_, boost::hana::type_impl<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::_>&; Pred = main()::<lambda(auto:1)>]’
/path/to/test.cpp:10:6:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/hana/detail/operators/comparable.hpp:40:33: error: use of ‘constexpr auto boost::hana::not_equal_t::operator()(X&&, Y&&) const [with X = boost::hana::type_impl<int>::_&; Y = const boost::hana::type_impl<float>::_&]’ before deduction of ‘auto’
         { return hana::not_equal(static_cast<X&&>(x), static_cast<Y&&>(y)); }
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm using Boost 1.65.1 and C++17.

Why doesn't my code work? From what I've seen, "use of some function returning `auto` before deduction of `auto`" usually comes from recursion, like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514665/use-of-auto-funcint-before-deduction-of-auto-in-c14), which makes sense. But there's no recursion here. There is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207315/use-of-boosthanaeval-if-t-before-deduction-of-auto) which seems closely related to my issue, but it's not exactly the same and the answer doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only missing an `#include`: `<boost/hana/not_equal.hpp>`.

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/6Msc1Wcfx)</kbd>

Comment: Ah, that was it, thanks. The error message actually kind of makes sense now. I assume one of the header files I did include had a forward declaration for `hana::not_equal`, which is why it didn't give me the clearer error message of it not being declared.

Comment: @nog642 : Yes, check out the `boost/hana/fwd` folder – it's kind of beautiful and horrifying. :-]